# Do even Brahmin men have Pitri-Rina?

Tags: brahmins, pitru

I find many Brahmin men in Puranas remaining unmarried. And no one cared. Do Brahmin men also have Pitri-Rina ?

Comment: One such example is Sage Jaratkaru, a Brahmin. People **cared** about his marriage. He was requested to get married to Manasa Devi for the purpose of begetting progeny and clearing his Pitr Rna. The others who are unmarried are those who have attained such a high liberated/ almost liberated state that their liberation liberates all generations above them. If those ancestors are liberated, they have paid off their Pitr Rna. However in either case Pitr Rna is very much existent for everyone irrespective of Brahminhood.

Comment: @Adiyarkku So, If a person gets liberated then his ancestors are also liberated ?

Answer (score 2):

> Manu Smriti 6.93. Those Brahmanas who thoroughly study the tenfold
> law, and after studying obey it, enter the highest state.
>
> 6.94. A twice-born man who, with collected mind, follows the tenfold law and has paid his (three) debts, may, after learning the Vedanta
> according to the prescribed rule, become an ascetic.

So, yes Brahmins also have the three debts of which the debt to the Pitris is one.