# Is it true that if a person gets liberated , his ancestors also get liberated?

Tags: moksha, pitru, mukti, ancestry

Is it true that if a person gets liberated [his ancestors also gets liberated](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/53930/do-even-brahmin-men-have-pitri-rina#comment166209_53930) ?